Firebase Data connect Reference Error in Schema
I have the following schema
type Store @table(key: "id") {
  id: String!                # Unique store ID
  name: String!              # Store name
  location: String           # Store location
  contactInfo: String        # Store contact info
}

type Category @table(key: ["name","store"]) {
  name: String!                       # Name of the Category (e.g. Drinks)
  store: Store! @ref                  # ID of the store this task belongs to
}

type StorageType @table(key: ["name","store"]){
  name: String!                       # Name of the Storage (e.g., DRY, Warehouse)
  store: Store! @ref                  # ID of the store this task belongs to
}

type Tag @table(key: ["name","store"]) {
  name: String!                       # Name of the product (e.g., Milk Tea)
  store: Store! @ref                  # ID of the store this task belongs to
}

type InventoryItemMetaData @table (key: ["sku","store"]) {
  id: UUID! @default(expr: "uuidV4()")
  name: String!
  sku: String!
  unit: String!
  lastUpdated: Timestamp! @default(expr: "request.time")
  threshold: Float            # minimum quantity we should have
  store: Store! @ref          # ID of the store this task belongs to
  category: Category @ref     # Used to categorize the inventory. Like Frozen, Dairy
  tags: [String]
  yield: Float @default(value: 100)
  storageTypeName: StorageType @ref # Used to categorize the storage type
}

I have the above schema and I get the below error for storageTypeName: StorageType @ref

